# What is the proper use case for コンペ先?

Tags: loanwords, business-japanese

As I understand the term コンペ先 translates as a "competitor" (*edit: from the examples in the answer, I think "contestant" seems more appropriate as there is an unspoken requirement for some contest or tender*).

In a business situation in which there is company X asking for bids, and three companies: A, B, and C take part in a tender, which of the following is the proper use case:

1. A calling B a コンペ先
2. X calling A a コンペ先

Or are both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this can be used in many ways, depending on the context.

X calling A a コンペ先 （コンペ先＝コンペ参加者・提案側）:

> - 仕事の引き合いがあった時は必ず、競合状態をクライアントにつくってもらうんです。つまり、**コンペ先**をそろえてもらい、正当に競争してもらうことをルール化しています。 ([source](http://www.watanabetakao.com/melma/malma_31.htm))
> - 「A社やB社にも相談するようにって言われているんだよね…」(略)有名企業で実績を残してきた人だけに、声掛けする**コンペ先**にも人脈があるようだった。([source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=DXMkprd88-wC&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&source=bl&ots=KEB3Sg6sgj&sig=o_EYhNmZ_GIJN64ksO_IB7-7tu8&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBmoVChMIhbKM8svhxwIVxp-UCh1vhgk7#v=onepage&q=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&f=false))
> - 「この提案内容で、**コンペ先**のXX氏に、担当してもらおうかな。あっちは、内容は時間不足でいまイチだったけど（略）頼もしかったからな…」([source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=iKGMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&source=bl&ots=owE0lVaNb0&sig=Ud6ZzxH24Yu6b8b7xCNQUssMmdA&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCWoVChMI-bz15MzhxwIVgqOUCh10uAHK#v=onepage&q=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&f=false))

A calling X a コンペ先 （コンペ先＝コンペ主催者）:

> - フォト**コンペ先**から『出品票の最終確認」ってメールが来たから、とあるURLをクリック。コンペ参加者の作品全部がアップロードされてみんなの作品を目の当たりにする・・・なう ([source](https://twitter.com/KEI__kay/status/38177161898754048))
> - **コンペ先**募集：現在、コンペに参加させてくださる少女漫画雑誌様（少女漫画でなくても勿論歓迎です）を募集しております。 ([source](http://ameblo.jp/fleur-tsugu/entry-11978212067.html))
> - コンペに参加することができました。このときに大切な出会いがありました。（中略）彼は**コンペ先**の地主さんのアドバイザーをしていたのです。([source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=wSIZSCMPB6QC&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&source=bl&ots=24CcM_98yJ&sig=4M-gVY6MikkOnfzLcTbpWesVM6A&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwB2oVChMI-bz15MzhxwIVgqOUCh10uAHK#v=onepage&q=%22%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E5%85%88%22&f=false))

A calling B a コンペ先 （コンペ先＝競合他社・ライバル):

> - 一緒に案件獲得に臨んだ技術者からは、「お前とオレが組んで**コンペ先**に負ける訳ないだろ」と言って頂けるようになりました。([source](https://job.rikunabi.com/2016/company/senior/r255900057/K108/))
> - 営業なのに何一つ売ることのできない状況を経験し、本当に需要がある物は何か？を常に考るようになりました。(略) 顧客から**コンペ先**（競合）が世界大手のBOSHやGEだと聞く事もしばしば・・・。([source](http://studyabroadberkeley.blogspot.jp/2010/04/blog-post.html))

Comment: Thank you, I've learnt more than I asked for. For first and third pattern a "contestant" would be more appropriate English term. But using it both for contestant and contest holder is quite unique, I guess.

Are you sure the second example in the second section (コンペ先募集) does not belong to the first one? X is looking for contestants.

Comment: She's a manga artist looking for a competition, so I think it belongs to the second pattern. 先 is a term which refers to "the other patry/side (as opposed to ourselves)".

Comment: You are perfectly right. I misunderstood the website concept (initially considered it an answer on a kind of forum, not a whole private site). And thus it is a very good example.